# What is the svn equivalent to Perforce's sync/resolve process?

Tags: svn, perforce

In Perforce, you typically do a two-step syncing process:
    p4 sync
    p4 resolve

The sync syncs your workspace to the repository and figures out which files are in conflict, and the resolve step does the merging and resolving of conflicts locally without checking anything in or otherwise affecting the repository.  And then you can run your regressions, make sure it still works in before you check it in.

What is the svn equivalent to doing this?  I know there's got to be a way to do this, but the obvious google searches aren't giving me any answers.

Comment: In subversion you can't `commit` if there are conflicts. So doing the "sync" would actually "block" you. At that point you have to use `svn update` to update your working directory, resolve the conflicts and commit again. Try looking [here](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/04/how-to-resolve-subversion-conflicts)

Comment: Okay...so according to the link, the proper sequence is:  
svn update  
<manually edit files>  
<run tests>  
svn commit  

Is there a more automated way to do the merging instead of having to manually edit it?  Perforce would do a lot of the merging for you, or you could pull up a GUI merge tool (Perforce's or tkdiff) and do the merge that way.  Is there any such option under SVN?

Comment: There is the `svn merge` command which should be able to solve trivial conflicts and should open a GUI tool to manually merge hard conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps are:

1. Use [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re28.html) to update the working copy to the HEAD or desired revision or [`svn merge`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html) to merge the changes from a different branch into the working copy.
2. For each conflicted file, svn creates/modifies four more files:

   1. `filename`: The original file is modified with markers indicating the lines in conflict.
   2. `filename.mine`: The original file.
   3. `filename.rBASE`: The unmodified version of the file at the working copy's revision number (BASE) before the update.
   4. `filename.rNEW`: The new version of the file from the update.
3. To fix the conflicts perform one of the following. Each removes the additional files created previously.

   1. Edit each file (`filename` in the above example) by hand to the desired state then call [`svn resolved`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.resolved.html) to indicate the conflict has been resolved.
   2. Use [`svn resolve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.resolve.html) to pick a particular version, either "base" (`filename.rBASE`), "working" (`filename`), "mine-full" (`filename.mine`) or "theirs-full" (`filename.rNEW`).
   3. Use [`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re25.html) to undo the update of that file.
4. Use [`svn commit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re06.html) to update the repository. This will not proceed until all conflicts have been resolved.

See [Resolving Conflicts (Merging Other's Changes)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch03s05.html#svn-ch-3-sect-5.4) for more information.